# Flutter and Dart try catch—catch does not fire

Tags: flutter, dart, try-catch, catch-block

Given the shortcode example below:

```
    ...
    print("1 parsing stuff");
    List<dynamic> subjectjson;
    try {
      subjectjson = json.decode(response.body);
    } on Exception catch (_) {
      print("throwing new error");
      throw Exception("Error on server");
    }
    print("2 parsing stuff");
    ...
```

I would *expect* the catch block to execute whenever the decoding fails. However, when a bad response returns, the terminal displays the exception and neither the catch nor the continuation code fires...

```
flutter: 1 parsing stuff
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: type
'_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type
'List<dynamic>'
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: is there a reason why you aren't just doing '}catch(_){}'

Comment: I am doing that now and that works, so I got rid of the on Exception clause.. I was under the assumption that incompatible types where an Exception as well. Should this not work?

Comment: What is the type that is actually caught? (e.g., do `catch (e) { print(e.runtimeType); }`).  It sounds like a bug if `json.decode` throws something that isn't an `Exception` or an `Error`.

Answer (score 89):

Functions can throw *anything*, even things that aren't an `Exception`:

```
void foo() {
  throw 42;
}
```

But the `on Exception` clause means that you are specifically catching *only* subclass of `Exception`.

As such, in the following code:

```
try {
  throw 42;
} on Exception catch (_) {
  print('never reached');
}
```

the `on Exception` will never be reached.

Comment: in catch (_) 

what is _

Comment: @puzzled Its typical naming reference that dictates that the value will never be used

Answer (score 59):

It is not a syntax error to have `on Exception catch` as someone else answered. However you need to be aware that the catch will not be triggered unless the error being thrown is of type `Exception`.

If you want to find out the exact type of the error you are getting, remove `on Exception` so that all errors are caught, put a breakpoint within the catch and check the type of the error. You can also use code similar to the following, if you want to do something for Exceptions, and something else for errors of all other types:

```
try {
  ...
} on Exception catch (exception) {
  ... // only executed if error is of type Exception
} catch (error) {
  ... // executed for errors of all types other than Exception
}
```

Comment: The Exception is the Top in hierarchy  for every exception

Comment: Thanks for the response, what makes it counter intuitive is that the error states:  Unhandled Exception: type .... so this causes me to think that the error actually is an exception and since I am catching on the base class Exception, I expected the catch to run.. but it does not.. So I guess the terminal output says 'unhandled exception' but the type is actually not an exception at all :-)

Answer (score 10):

Use:

```
try {
  ...
} on Exception catch (exception) {
  ... // only executed if error is of type Exception
} catch (error) {
  ... // executed for errors of all types other than Exception
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to "enter [an] image description [there]". It takes seconds and helps describe what people are in for if they were to click the link.

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 6):

The rule is that exception handling should be from *detailed* exceptions to *general* exceptions in order to make the operation to fall in the proper catch block and give you more information about the error, like catch blocks in the following method:

```
Future<int> updateUserById(int userIdForUpdate, String newName) async {
  final db = await database;
  try {
    int code = await db.update('tbl_user', {'name': newName},
        whereArgs: [userIdForUpdate], where: "id = ?");
    return code;
  }
  on DatabaseException catch(de) {
    print(de);
    return 2;
  }
  on FormatException catch(fe) {
    print(fe);
    return 2;
  }
  on Exception catch(e) {
    print(e);
    return 2;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
    print("1 parsing stuff");
    List<dynamic> subjectjson;
    try {
      subjectjson = json.decode(response.body);
    } catch (_) { .   // <-- removing the on Exception clause
      print("throwing new error");
      throw Exception("Error on server");
    }
    print("2 parsing stuff");
    ...
```

This works, but what is the rationale behind this? Isn't the type inconsistency an Exception?

Comment: This is not an answer. Can you move it to the question, please? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 4):

As everybody or most of the people said, try to know exactly what error you are getting:

```
try{
}
catch(err){
    print(err.runTimeType);
}
```

runTimeType will give you the type of data or exception you are getting or to put simple the exception itself.
And then do whatever you want. (Like if you are not getting the exception of what you expected, then try to fix that issue or change the exception.)

Another option is to go with general form.
Using the simple catch which will prompt every time.

Answer (score 3):

The other possible reason for the catch bloc not to fire, as pointed out in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66664941/throw-custom-formatexception-using-throw-and-try-to-handle-it-by-try-on-dart), is missing brackets when throwing an exception.

Must write `throw FormatException()` instead of `throw FormatException`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a issue with try catch but my problem was the API that I send http request, doesn't response of my request so that is why my request doesn't response anything and try catch didn't catch the error. So I suggest you to add **timeout** to your request so that if your api doesn't response your request after a while you can cancel your request with **timeout**. Here is an example how to use it;

```
try {
  final response = await http.post(Url).timeout(Duration(seconds: 5));
} catch (error) {
  print(error)
}
```