# throw custom FormatException using "throw" and try to handle it by try on . Dart Language

Tags: dart, formatexception

I tried to throw a custom FormatException by me and try to handle by using try on

```
try {
   print (' Enter Your age ') ; 
throw FormatException ;
}
on FormatException {
  print('Stop you enter invalid value  ') ;

}
```

output : didn't handle the exception ?
i try using **catch(e)** and worked fine !

> My Question is Why on FormatException won't handle the exception ??

the syntax of tryOn i wrote is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`throw FormatException` throws the `FormatException` *type* (i.e, an object of type `Type`), but `on FormatException` expects to catch an *instance* a `FormatException`.

Use `throw FormatException()` instead (optionally with an error string).